# From plus objects to one array, javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb

I am in this situation:

```
[{"title":"007 Legends"},{"title":"0 Day Attack on Earth"},.....]
```

result of this query:

```
`exports.findAll = function(req, res){
    items.find({},{_id:0},function(err, results) {
    return res.send(results);
    });
 };
`
```

I need to convert those objects in array:
`[007 Legends, 0 Day Attack on Earth, 007 Racing, 0D Beat Drop..]`, so i can return results  as array  and use it like endpoint to autocomplete jquery

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do [map on the mongodb cursor](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.map/):

```
items.find({}, {_id:0})
    .map(function(item){ 
        return item.title; 
    }, function (err, results) {
        return res.send(results)
    })
```

In mongoose you first need to get the mongodb cursor. You can do it via the collection property of a Mongoose Model. 
Try the following code:

```
items.collection.find({}, {_id:0}, function(err, cursor){
    cursor
        .map(function(item){ 
            return item.title; 
        })
        .toArray(function(err, results){
            return res.send(results)
        })
})
```

Comment: im trying to use your solution but i'm having this error: TypeError: items.find(...).map is not a function

Comment: @Fen What library do you use for accessing database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

#### Syntax

> *arr.map(callback[, thisArg])*

```js
var json = [{"title":"007 Legends"},{"title":"0 Day Attack on Earth"}]
var arr = json.map(function(el){ return el.title; });
alert(arr);
```